# Error with AES decryption method

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, aes

I'm having real issues with decryption and don't know how to resolve this 'java.crypto.BadPaddingException'. I have had a similar previous system working just fine, now I've been halted for the last week. I have read many stackoverflow threads, but none really solve my issue...unless of course, I simply didn't understand it.

My issue arises in the login method where it says: `byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(p.getBytes());`

```
public void register() {
    // ENCRYPT PASSWORD
    try {
        String key = username; // 128bit key (16*8)
        String text = password;

        // CREATE KEY AND CIPHER
        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        // ENCRYPT THE TEXT
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Encrypted: " + new String(encrypted));

        // SET VARIABLE FOR SAVING
        p = new String(new String(encrypted));
        System.out.println("p: " + new String(p));
        System.out.println("p: " + password);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // ENCRYPT QUESTION
    try {
        String key = username; // 128bit key (16*8)
        String text = question;

        // CREATE KEY AND CIPHER
        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        // ENCRYPT THE TEXT
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Encrypted: " + new String(encrypted));

        // SET VARIABLE FOR SAVING
        q = new String(new String(encrypted));
        System.out.println("q: " + new String(q));
        System.out.println("q: " + question);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // ENCRYPT ANSWER
    try {
        String key = username; // 128bit key (16*8)
        String text = answer;

        // CREATE KEY AND CIPHER
        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        // ENCRYPT THE TEXT
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Encrypted: " + new String(encrypted));

        // SET VARIABLE FOR SAVING
        an = new String(new String(encrypted));
        System.out.println("an: " + new String(an));
        System.out.println("an: " + answer);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    // SAVE DATA IN LICENSE FILE
    try {
        File file = new File("C://Welcome/License.txt");
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

        //bw.write(new String(u));
        //bw.newLine();
        bw.write(new String(p));
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(new String(q));
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write(new String(an));
        bw.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    // CREATE A FOLDER FOR FILES
    try {
        File dir = new File("C://IronFortress/Files");
        dir.mkdir();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void login() {
    // LOAD PASSWORD, QUESTION AND ANSWER HASHES
    String fileName = "C:/Welcome/License.txt";
    String line0 = null;
    String line1 = null;
    String line2 = null;

    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        if((line0 = br.readLine()) != null){
            p = (line0);
        }
        if((line1 = br.readLine()) != null){
            q = (line1);
        }
        if((line2 = br.readLine()) != null){
            an = (line2);
        }

        br.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    // DECRYPT STORED PASSWORD
    try {
        String key = username; // 128bit key (16*8)
        String text = p;

        // CREATE KEY AND CIPHER
        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

        // DECRYPT THE TEXT
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(p.getBytes());
        System.out.println("Decrypted Pass: " + new String(decrypted));

                // COMPARE VALUES
                if (password.equals(new String(decrypted))){
                //if (tf2.getText().equals(new String(decrypted))){
                    welcome.setVisible(true);
                    bg.setVisible(false);
                    l.setVisible(false);
                    tf1.setVisible(false);
                    tf2.setVisible(false);
                    b3.setVisible(false);
                    b4.setVisible(false);
                }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    at IronFortress.intro.login(intro.java:327)
    at IronFortress.intro.actionPerformed(intro.java:482)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is `new String(encrypted)`. Ciphertexts are made up of arbitrary bytes. Some of those bytes are unprintable. Creating a string directly from those bytes with the default system encoding will silently throw away some bytes. So your ciphertext will be broken and the plaintext cannot be recovered.

In order to encrypt arbitrary length plaintexts a padding is (automatically) applied before encryption. When the decryption runs, it will try to remove the previously applied padding. If the ciphertext is altered in some way (depends on the mode of operation) it is possible to detect this manipulation by checking if the padding is valid (it has a very specific format). You'll get a BadPaddingException if the padding wasn't valid and couldn't have been removed.

If you want to produce textual ciphertext output, then you need to properly encode your ciphertext for example with Base64 or Hex. Then you would decode it before decryption.

---

**Other issues:**

- `Cipher.getInstance("AES")` is not fully qualified. You need to use a fully qualified string to prevent surprises when you change systems. For example `Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")`. You current cipher string probably defaults to ECB mode...
- Don't use ECB mode! Use CBC mode with a random IV. The IV doesn't have to be secret, so you can prepend it to the ciphertext.
- Always specify the encoding that you use: `new String(bytes, "UTF-8")` and `string.getBytes("UTF-8")`. Otherwise, you won't be able to decrypt your ciphertexts on another system that has a different system encoding.
- `new String(new String(encrypted));` won't make it more of a string than `new String(encrypted)`.
- You don't need to encode your ciphertext into Base64 or Hex. You can continue using `byte[]` and switch from FileWriter to FileOutputStream.

Comment: When printed out on the console, both entered input and decrypted string match exactly. Does this change anything, or is base64/Hex encoding the thing to start looking into?

Comment: *"When printed out on the console, both entered input and decrypted string match exactly."* If this is true, then you couldn't have gotten an exception.

Comment: Ima start having a read up about what youve mentioned, thanks for the heads up, im going to do a bit of research and ill be back shortly.